# Magento 2 : Create duplicate cart price rule using existing cart price rule id

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.3.1

I want to duplicate the cart price rule in magento 2 by using cart price rule id. is there any way?

Comment: Can you please give more details? such as do you want to achieve this via program or admin side configuration because from the admin side it is not possible as there is no duplicate feature available in Magento 2. If programmatically you wanna achieve please mention the scenario and file. Thank you

Comment: Can you please describe some more requirement into the details what you are looking for?

Comment: I need to duplicate same coupon code with different name but the all condition should be same. Like product. Please just guide me which are files to be override. what are the actual table for this like sales_rule